# java phpmyadmin "Is it possible to put a code inside a database"

Tags: phpmyadmin, appium

Is it possible to put a code inside a database, call it and execute the code, or are databases only specialized in text and numbers?

Example:
"I want to put the following code in a database and invoke it inside a java file"

try {
MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Account");
el1.click();
}
catch(Exception exp){driver.quit();};

Comment: That code is *just text* to the database, and can be *stored as text*. How would the database even “run” the code?

Comment: As far as the **other problem**, of executing some Java provided in text .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820995/execute-code-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: Can this text be called?
The Java program considers it text or code

Comment: Java source code *is represented as text* (in .java files normally). It can be edited with any text editor. It is how a poem *is represented as text*.

Comment: thank you my friend